# Slack API Socket Mode and asyncio

Tags: python-asyncio, slack-api

I'm writing some middle-ware in Python that uses Socket Mode. Non-async testing works fine.  But the connect() call fails:

```
app_token='xapp-XXX'
bot_token='xoxb-XXX'

web_client = AsyncWebClient(bot_token)
sm_client = SocketModeClient(app_token=app_token, web_client=web_client)

sm_client.connect()
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapper.py", line 57, in <module>
    sm_client.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/slack_sdk/socket_mode/builtin/client.py", line 132, in connect
    self.wss_uri = self.issue_new_wss_url()
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/slack_sdk/socket_mode/client.py", line 48, in issue_new_wss_url
    return response["url"]
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncWebClient.apps_connections_open' was never awaited
```

I can't find anything in the API or SDK documentation about how to use AsyncWebClient in a Socket Mode application.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your traceback, it is referencing the `builtin` client, aka the [concurrent client](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/blob/83c6f9c6d24592cdfb1632dc761c4d160512a2b6/slack_sdk/socket_mode/builtin/client.py#L27). You're probably importing this:

```
from slack_sdk.socket_mode import SocketModeClient
```

You need to use the [async client](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/blob/83c6f9c6d24592cdfb1632dc761c4d160512a2b6/slack_sdk/socket_mode/aiohttp/__init__.py#L28) if you're using the `AsyncWebClient`:

```py
from slack_sdk.socket_mode.aiohttp import SocketModeClient
```

Comment: Yeah, that was it.  I forgot to update this in Feb.